# Using a string, to give a name to a new string

Tags: python, list

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have some files in a directory, and I made a list of these:

```
filesInDir = os.listdir("scanfiles")
```

And after I got these, I'm trying to split the lines into seperate lists:

```
for files in filesInDir:
    sourceFile = open("scanfiles/" + files, "r")
    dynmicNameList = sourceFile.read().splitlines()
```

I would like it so that the array name is the file's name. So far I've only seen way more complicated scenarios for this problem. But I can't get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a dictionary for those lines, not local variables:

```
lines = {}

for files in filesInDir:
    sourceFile = open("scanfiles/" + files, "r")
    lines[files] = sourceFile.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it as usual! +1

Comment: Yeah I need to study my data types. Thanks for the lightning fast reply! Off-topic: Ik heet ook Martijn :)

Comment: Lol ik dacht dat mijn Username niet mijn naam bevatte

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror: Dat zag ik! Finally, someone that can spell my name.. :-P Being a 'Nederlandse Noor', having been a 'Nederlandse Amerikaan' I am used to the misspellings, of course.

Comment: Going even more off-topic but what's the most used mistake in your name? Most online friends struggle with my name and make it Martin.

Comment: Mostly it'll become Martin. But I've seen Martjin, Martijin, Martjn, Martinjn, etc. It gets to be more fun when people try to *pronounce* it. And then there are the Americans introducing me as the Danish guy...

Comment: Haha I would love the migrate to the US with the name Giel or Gerard. but the 'ij' pronunciation gives most people a hard time as well. Thanks for the help Martijn!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an associative Array

Comment: In python those are called a mapping. The default type `dict` is the canonical implementation of the data structure.